# Java Classpath patch concept for WAR files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath

There is a classpath patch concept frequently used by adding patch.jar file in classpath before main jar file. I have used this method for running J2SE applications.

I wonder if same concept is applied for J2EE projects such as in WAR files. If so how I can make it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there's any guaranteed ordering among different JAR files in `WEB-INF/lib`, but it *is* guaranteed ([Servlet Specification version 3.0](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr315/index.html), section 10.5) that `WEB-INF/classes` will be ahead of all the `WEB-INF/lib` JAR files.  So you could put your "patch" class files under `WEB-INF/classes` instead of putting them in a JAR.

Comment: let me try then I will share my experience.